# How to remove Google Account after factory reset

Tags: google-account, frp

I have been given a Huawei smartphone that needed a new screen, which I've just had replaced. I now want to sell the phone.

Am I forced to enter the Google account of the previous owner in order to complete the start up process after a factory reset?

Can I then delete the old Google account ready for the new owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done a factory reset without removing the Google account first, then you have triggered FRP.

Although it is not nice, there are some tutorials on YouTube or WWW which work on some phones and help in bypassing the FRP. If that doesn't work, the Huawei customer service should have the tools to erase the FRP/persist partition and remove the requirement to add the previous owner's Google account.

Lastly, it is better to ask the previous owner to just come over and login once using his account. You can then remove his account and issue a fresh factory reset. Now it will be ready for resale.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the way forward, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have executed the factory reset properly then the phone is not asking you for a Google Account of the previous owner, it is asking you to provide **your** Google Account so you can best use features offered by the Android phone. If you don't have an account yet you can also create it with your phone directly providing that you have internet access.

Comment: properly means? enabled OEM unlocking in developer options and/or removed google account before reset?

Comment: I don't think this is true. Android remembers the owning user account even after factory reset. The account should be removed by the account owner, either through logging on, or by accessing the account on another device and removing it from the list of active devices on the account.